# Making jumpy head tags much smoother

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I run this code, the headlines kind of jump rather than having a smooth transition. And I would like to fix that. I tried adding the fadeIn and fadeOut which made it more smooth. But still, when I click the headlines, they seem to jump up and down. Here is the code that I started working with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.info').click(function(){
        $('.info').each(function(){
            $(this).next().fadeOut("slow");
        });
        $(this).next().fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

In order to make the transitions smoother, I would like the following things: when I click on a headline, I would like the headline to fade out, move up, and then fade in along with the text that is supposed to go with that headline. So I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.info').click(function(){
        $('.info').each(function(){
            $('info').next().fadeOut("slow"); 
            $(this).next().fadeOut("slow");
        });
        $(this).next().fadeIn("slow");
        $('info').next().fadeIn("slow"); 
    });
});

<div>
    <a class="info" p style="font-size:30px" href="javascript:void(0);">Header 1</a>
    <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">Text 1</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <a class="info" href="javascript:void(0);">Header 2</a>
    <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">Text 2</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <a class="info" href="javascript:void(0);">Header 3</a>
    <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">Text 3</h1>
</div>
```

But this didn't change anything and didn't produce the effect that I desire. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: What is "move up" ? Note , `.each()` would animate all `.info` elements

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: you aren't waiting for the fadeout before you start fadein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`slideUp`**](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/), [**`slideDown`**](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) and [**`slideToggle`**](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) might be what you're looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.info').click(function(){
        $('.info').not(this).next().slideUp("slow");
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <a class="info" p style="font-size:30px" href="javascript:void(0);">Header 1</a>
    <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">Text 1</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <a class="info" href="javascript:void(0);">Header 2</a>
    <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">Text 2</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <a class="info" href="javascript:void(0);">Header 3</a>
    <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">Text 3</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `.each()` , using `complete` function of `.fadeOut()` , `.parent()` to select parent `div` of clicked `.info` , `.insertBefore()` to "move up" container of clicked `.info` element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.info').click(function() {
    $(this).next().fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $(this).parent()
      .insertBefore($("div:first"))
      .find(".infoText")
      .fadeIn("slow")
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  <a class="info" p style="font-size:30px" href="javascript:void(0);">Header 1</a>
  <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">Text 1</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="info" href="javascript:void(0);">Header 2</a>
  <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">Text 2</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="info" href="javascript:void(0);">Header 3</a>
  <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">Text 3</h1>
</div>
```